# Interpret Dynamic value of javascrript Variable to textbox id

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 t += '<td ><input type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" id ="text"." + i +"  name="tx"/></td>';
```

Iam building dynamic Table with the Text boxes in each row iam looking to have the textbox id genrated with the variable `i` dynamically. Iam not able to get the value of variable `i` appended dynamically . when i try to view source `+?="" +="" .?=""` in the input tag.How to append the value of `i` to the textbox id generated dynamically

Comment: Is this: ` t += '<td ><input type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" id ="text'+i+'"  name="tx"/></td>';` what you're looking for?​

Comment: Iam looking to append the Dynamic value of  javascript variable "i"  to textboxid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need:

```
t += '<td ><input type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" id ="text' + i + '" name="tx"/></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
t += '<td ><input type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" id ="text"."' + i + '"  name="tx"/></td>';
```

Since your enclosing whole string with single quote, you need to split based on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
t += '<td><input type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" id="text.' + i + '" name="tx"/></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be manipulating the DOM directly and not just using flat text as HTML. Additionally you need to split your string. A much better way to do this would be:

```
var td = document.createElement('td');
td.setAttribute('id', 'text' + i);
```